# Genymotion stuck after reboot

Tags: android, sdk, genymotion

When I try to reboot genymotion from Program Files\Genymotion\tools with command `adb reboot` it gets stucked. I tried to update genymotion but it does not help. Genymotion version Version 2.9.0
I'm using native genymotion android tools

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the `RAM size` for your genymotion device and restart again..!!

Comment: It didn't help .